# How to execute a project with several classes?

Tags: scala

I started with one class

```
object A {
   import my.Result._
   ...
}
```

And I would compile and execute it like this: `scalac A.scala; scala -classpath . A`

Now I added a second class B ending up with:

```
package my
object A {
   import my.Result._
   ....
}
```

and

```
package my

object B extends Enumeration {
    ...
}
```

I compile them with `scalac A.scala B.scala`
But I cannot manage to execute that.

```
$ scala -classpath . A
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot figure out how to run target: A
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.scala$tools$nsc$GenericRunnerCommand$$guessHowToRun(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:38)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:48)
    ...
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

That may be because the class files are now in a new directory '`my`', so I'm trying to change the classpath.

```
$ scala -classpath /home/absolute/path/my A
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: A (wrong name: my/A)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    ...
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

Even changing into the new directory won't help

```
$ cd my; scala -classpath . A
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: A (wrong name: my/A)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    ...
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

**Progress:**
I made it work, yet not quite as I wanted to:

```
$ scalac A.scala B.scala
$ scala
> import my._
> my.A.main(new Array[String](2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling into a jar and the use that jar as classpath.

To compile:

```
scalac -cp my.jar A.scala B.scala
```

To run:

```
scala -cp my.jar A
```

Comment: I still get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot figure out how to run target: A`  
Are you sure about the first line? No jar is created, just a directory.  
[This site](http://www.cs.trinity.edu/~kseitz/tutorials/scalaWebApplet/WebAppletsInScala/node4.html) describes a more complicated approach, but I had really hoped for a simpler solution.